# How to set selected text from drop down

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

When I select a dropdown item then I need a text from a selected item of a drop-down, For a long time, I am not getting any solution to my problem. I made a common directive for this so that I can get the text for all dropdown when I used my directive. Here is my code

**app.component.html**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
    Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<div>
    <p>Come from directive: {{selectedText}} </p>
    <p>Come from Parent Component - {{selectedProp}}</p>
    <select [psSelectText]="'selectedText'"  name="selectedProp" [(ngModel)]="selectedProp" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option *ngFor="let i of arrayList" value="{{i.value}}">{{i.text}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br>
<button (click)="hitMe()">Hit me</button>
```

**My directive:**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, SimpleChanges, OnChanges, Output, EventEmitter, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { SelectText } from './select-text.model';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][psSelectText]',
  providers: [NgModel],
  host: {
    '(ngModelChange)': 'onInputChange($event)'
  }
})
export class PsSelectText implements OnChanges {
  @Input('psSelectText') selectedText: string;
  @Input('ngModel') selectedModel: NgModel;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, public model: NgModel, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }


  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(this.el)
    if (changes.selectedModel) {
      // this.selectedText.valueAccessor.writeValue(changes.selectedModel.currentValue);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.viewContainerRef['_view'].component[this.selectedText] =
          this.el.nativeElement.selectedOptions[0].text;
      }, 0);
    }
  }

  onInputChange(event) {
    // Only get selected change
  }
}
```

> I have already done this by passing a single variable
>   `[psSelectText]="'selectedText'",` but I want to pass an object
>   property selectedText2.text, here need to set the text of dropdown to
>   selectedText2.text property into directive.

My need, I want to pass the attribute like this way:

```
[psSelectText]="selectedText2.text"
```

And set the text of dropdown from my directive to this field `selectedText2.text`

**Has there any way to do this?** Thank you very much.

Actually, need to change here:

```
// "this.selectedText2.text" this property will come from dynamically,
        this.viewContainerRef['_view'].component[this.selectedText2.text] =
          this.el.nativeElement.selectedOptions[0].text;
```

**Demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dropdown-selected-text

https://angular-dropdown-selected-text.stackblitz.io

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you want? seems to be confusing by your question.

Comment: I need a directive which will set the text of drop-down when dropdown will select. I have already done this by passing a single variable [psSelectText]="'selectedText'", but I want to pass an object property selectedText2.text, here need to set the value of selectedText2.text filed from directive.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to

- pass an object to your directive instead of a text
- assign a value on the screen as per the passed object (via directive)

Kindly take a look at this and let me know if this is what you wanted ?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wbu8us

**ps-select-text.directive.ts** & **app.component.html** are below

```js
/* tslint:disable:member-ordering */
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, SimpleChanges, OnChanges, Output, EventEmitter, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { SelectText } from './app.component';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][psSelectText]',
  providers: [NgModel],
  host: {
    '(ngModelChange)': 'onInputChange($event)'
  }
})
export class PsSelectText implements OnChanges {
  @Input('psSelectText') selectedText: SelectText;
  @Input('ngModel') selectedModel: NgModel;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, public model: NgModel, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }


  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    /*
    console.log(this.el);
    console.log(this.selectedText);
    console.log(this.viewContainerRef['_view'].component);
    */
    
    if (changes.selectedModel) {
      // this.selectedText.valueAccessor.writeValue(changes.selectedModel.currentValue);
      setTimeout(() => {

        if (this.selectedText) {
          this.viewContainerRef['_view'].component.selectedText = "(from inside Directive)" + this.selectedText.stText;
        }

        // "this.selectedText" this property will come from dynamically,
          /* 
        this.viewContainerRef['_view'].component[this.selectedText] = 
          this.el.nativeElement.selectedOptions[0].stText;
          */
      }, 0);
    }
  }

  onInputChange(event) {
    // Only get selected change
  }
}


/*
Copyright 2017-2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
*/
```

```html
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
 Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<div>
 <p>Come from directive: <mark>{{selectedText}}</mark> </p>
 <p>Come from Parent Component [ngModel]: 
    <span *ngIf="selectedText2"> 
      v: <mark>{{selectedText2.stValue}}</mark> & 
      t: <mark>{{selectedText2.stText}}</mark> 
    </span> 
  </p>
 <select [psSelectText]="selectedText2"  name="selectedProp" [(ngModel)]="selectedText2" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option *ngFor="let i of arrayList" [ngValue]="i" >{{i.stText}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br>
<button (click)="hitMe()">Hit me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But if your object is different suppose, you have a gender drop-down which objects property like gender name, that for causes you do not know the object and property like this .selectedText.stText, so need to pass any object and any property into the directive.

Comment: You can change the SelectText object to include any number of fields (name, gender etc.)... on selection of a particular option, the specific object (from the array) will all be passed to the directive (using the existing code above)...

Comment: You have written this line
this.viewContainerRef['_view'].component.selectedText = "(from inside Directive)" + this.selectedText.stText;

these below property will not be fixed, you have only directive name "psSelectText" and Property selectedText2.text into html

(component.selectedText
this.selectedText.stText;)

Comment: i didn't understand, you want the left side  [this.viewContainerRef['_view'].component.selectedText] to be dynamic? i have updated the stackblitz with console printing out the things you can assign value to [console.log(this.viewContainerRef['_view'].component.selectedText);] ... can you please explain your point?

Answer (score 0):

The following code is coding

**HTML:**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
    Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<div>
    <p>Come from directive: {{selectedText}} </p>
    <p>Come from Parent Component - {{selectedProp}}</p>
    <select [psSelectText]="'selectedText'"  name="selectedProp" [(ngModel)]="selectedProp" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option *ngFor="let i of arrayList" value="{{i.value}}">{{i.text}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br>
<button (click)="hitMe()">Hit me</button>
```

**DIRECTIVE:**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, SimpleChanges, OnChanges, Output, EventEmitter, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { SelectText } from './select-text.model';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][psSelectText]',
  providers: [NgModel],
  host: {
    '(ngModelChange)': 'onInputChange($event)'
  }
})
export class PsSelectText implements OnChanges {
  @Input('psSelectText') selectedText: string;
  @Input('ngModel') selectedModel: NgModel;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, public model: NgModel, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }


  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(this.el)
    if (changes.selectedModel) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.viewContainerRef['_view'].component[this.selectedText] =
          this.el.nativeElement.selectedOptions[0].text;
      }, 0);
    }
  }

  onInputChange(event) {
    // Only get selected change
  }
}
```

**COMPONENT:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SelectText } from './select-text.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  selectedProp: string;
  selectedText: any = "yellow";
  selectedText2: SelectText;
  arrayList: Array<any> = [];

  hitMe() {
    this.selectedProp = "2";
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.selectedText = new SelectText();    
    this.arrayList.push({ value: 1, text: "First Value" });
    this.arrayList.push({ value: 2, text: "Second Value" });
    this.arrayList.push({ value: 3, text: "Third Value" });
    this.arrayList.push({ value: 4, text: "Fourth Value" });
    this.arrayList.push({ value: 5, text: "Fifth Value" });
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dropdown-selected-text):**